# My Datagrid only shows Header and empty rows

Tags: wpf, excel, datagrid, datatable, interop

I have a project where i first use the method TextToColumns of Interop Excel to convert a txt file into an Excel
Then using the IExcelDataReader (see here http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/) I have populated a DataTable , but when I set my Datagrid.Itemssource property to the DefaultView of the DataTable it shows the headers and only empty rows without values.
I tried debugging on the event "datagrid_LoadingRow" and checked out that Row.ItemArray does not have only null values, but they are not all null. The array has the right values, so I can't understand what's the problem. 
I can't see some Excel files on a Datagrid, only the headers. Is a problem with the DataTable or with the Datagrid?
I can see some Excel files... That's why  I am so confused.
Should I use another control more suitable?
Thanks in advance,

---

Mattia P.

EDIT: There's another issue. How can I use the method TextToColumns of Interop Excel to separate a txt file with different delimeters? Sometimes it does not work properly (some headers are cutted). I use it twice: here's the code.

```
cell.TextToColumns(destinationRange,
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlFixedWidth); 
//For fixed width delimiters

cell.TextToColumns(destinationRange, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited, XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierNone, false, true, true, false, false, true, "|",fieldInfoArray);
//For general delimeters
```

Thanks again.

EDIT PART 2:
If  I change MANUALLY the excel first row (that will be my datagrid headers), the Datagrid shows the data.
I can't figure out why...

Comment: if you are able to load datatable from excel. this should work with dt.DefaultView. check your property matchups.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, but what do you mean in this case with property matchups? What should I do?